# How query SQL with a user selected order

Tags: android, sql, sql-order-by, android-room

I'm trying to set up a user-selected SQL Query in Android Room.

```
    @Query("SELECT * FROM wrestler_table ORDER BY :columnName :sortOrder LIMIT :size")
    LiveData<List<WrestlersEntity>> getAllWrestlers(String columnName, String sortOrder, int size);
```

Android stuido is listing the sortOrder in the query as an error.

```
    ASC, BETWEEN, COLLATE, DESC, IN, LIMIT, comma or semicolon expected, got ':sortOrder'
```

I want the sortOrder to be a variable so the user can change the order the data is returned in. Any thoughts on what I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you cannot pass the sort direction as query parameter. Not only SQLite, but most RDBMS do not allow this.

The following expression should do the trick:

```
ORDER BY 
    CASE WHEN :sortOrder = 'DESC' THEN :columnName END DESC,
    CASE WHEN :sortOrder = 'ASC' THEN :columnName END ASC
LIMIT :size"
```

Alternatively, you can also concatenate the sort direction directly in the query string instead of passing it as a parameter.

Comment: Your first solution worked, I've tried your alternate solution as well but it didn't work, the query returned the results in the order they were entered in the Database.